# AWS Load Balancer from Endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-elb

I have an endpoint for an AWS load balancer, something like:

> blah-blah-blah-123123123.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.

I can't seem to find a boto3 call to look up the load balancer by endpoint. I did try treating it as a name, but got an error telling me that names can not be longer than 32 characters.

What API call(s) do I need to get my load balancer info from the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

There is [describe_load_balancers](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.describe_load_balancers) which returns, among other things:

> DNSName The public DNS name of the load balancer.

For classic load balancer, there is also a function of the same name [describe_load_balancers](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elb.html#ElasticLoadBalancing.Client.describe_load_balancers).

Comment: But I don't want the DNS name... that's the one piece of information I already have

Comment: @REW The endpoint is dns name. What kind of other endpoint do you require? AWS service endpoint for ELB?

Comment: I need the load balancer info. I already have the endpoint. See my answer to the question.

Comment: @REW I see. I guess it would be simpler to ask "What is the name of my load balancer"?

Comment: Agreed. I thought the full endpoint was the same as the load balancer name, which caused all the confusion (and API failures during my testing) in the first place.

Comment: @REW Anyway, glad it got sorted out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. The name, in my above example of

> blah-blah-blah-123123123.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.

would be something like **blah-blah-blah**

From a command line, the command would be

> aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --names blah-blah-blah

Simple translation from there to the [describe_load_balancers](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.describe_load_balancers) call mentioned by @Marcin.